# How to recover from grub rescue after replacing boot disk

Tags: grubrescue

I had 2 hard disk in my laptop. Primary Disk with RedHat and secondary disk with Ubuntu installed on it. Both disk were able to boot separately and I used to flip the OS of my choice by updating the bios settings. Every thing was just fine until my secondary disk failed. I replaced the failed secondary disk and  installed ubuntu on the new secondary disk. By mistake I installed the boot loader on to the primary disk instead of the secondary disk. To recover from this, I re-installed Ubuntu in the secondary disk and installed the boot loader to the secondary disk. Now I am able to boot my secondary disk.

Here is the problem now, my primary disk wont boot its getting halted with the grub rescue prompt saying invalid UUID. I tried attempt to boot from the grub rescue but did not help.

My primary disk has a separate partition and mounted as /boot and root filesystem is on LVM with luks. I am able to mount the primary disk separately and   access the files in there just that I am unable to boot from the primary disk.

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: In Ubuntu add the LVM 2 drivers:  sudo apt-get install lvm2`, then mount the Redhat partitions. And see if grub2's os-prober then finds the Redhat install to add to boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to get the issue fixed. Thought of posting here in case any one gets into similar issue.

I booted the system with the Redhat install CD and got into rescue mode.Once I booted with the rescue mode, everything was easy. Here are the commands that I issues to get the boot loader fixed for my Redhat.

1. Boot the system on Redhat installation disk in rescue mode.
2. Mounted the boot filesystem into /mnt/boot
3. Ensured the device map looks good.

   ```
    cat /mnt/boot/grub/device.map]
    (hd0)    /dev/sda
   ```
4. grub --device-map /mnt/boot/grub/device.map
5. root (hd0,0)
6. setup (hd0)

Rebooted the system and life back to normal :)